# Reference a controller function for a dynamically created DOM element

Tags: controller, onclick, helper

In my helper, I have a function that is dynamically creating multiple . I want the onclick event to trigger a controller function : I tried the following code :

```
accordionWholeDiv.setAttribute('onclick', '{!c.unfoldAccordion}');
```

but it gives me this error :
[image: Error my brower gives me]

I tried many solutions but couldn't find one working... Can somebody help me ? Thank you :-)

Comment: `c` in your javascript controller is referencing an apex controller method. Are you trying to call apex?

Comment: No I'm simply trying to tie the onclick event to a controller function !

Comment: Does `unfoldAccordion` function already exist in your component's controller?

Comment: can you add this event to the element mark up? `<input type="button" onclick="{!c.unfoldAccordion} value="unfold""/>`

Comment: Yes the **unfoldAccordion** function exists in my controller. And when I code an element in my component and set the onclick to call this particular controller function, it works as expected !

Comment: Does that accomplish what you set out to do?

Comment: Yes, the problem might only come from the fact that I try to dynamically link an onlick event, maybe the logic doesn't understand the controller reference ?

Comment: Have you tried setting it as `accordionWholeDiv.setAttribute("onclick": cmp.getReference("c.unfoldAccordion"));`-- as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I just tried @JayantDas but it gives me the same error : the c is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can make the dynamic created element to be a component, you can then add the onlick event logic on that "normal" component controller

Comment: Yes this is a solution, though I have to rethink some of the architecture... I will give it a try later, will give feedbacks thanks !

Comment: it will also be easier to manipulate/change later on, good luck.